# Creating a CLR Table Valued Function

Tags: sql-server, clr

Am trying to create a simple table valued CLR function, which takes a comma separated string as a parameter, splits it up and returns it as multiple rows

Following a few online tutorials I ended up at:

```
[SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillRow",TableDefinition="val nvarchar(1000)")]
public static IEnumerable SqlFunction1(SqlString val)
{
    string[] splitStr = val.Value.Split(',');
    return splitStr;
}
private static void FillRow(Object obj, out SqlString str)
{
    object[] row = (object[])obj;
    str = (string)row[0];
}
```

However, executing it using

```
select * from dbo.SqlFunction1('1,2,3,4,5')
```

Returns the following error

```
Msg 6260, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
An error occurred while getting new row from user defined Table Valued Function : 
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object[]'.
System.InvalidCastException: 
   at UserDefinedFunctions.FillRow(Object obj, SqlString& str)
.
```

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment, I realised it was senseless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking a string reference and try to cast it to an object array, which causes the InvalidCastException.

Your `SqlFunction1` method returns an array of strings, so the `FillRow` method will be called with a string reference. Cast the object reference back to string, and then create a `SqlString` value from it:

```
private static void FillRow(Object obj, out SqlString str) {
  string row = (string)obj;
  str = new SqlString(row);
}
```

Comment: Could you point me to more reading material on what exactly is happening here? Is it that `SqlFunction1` is called, and for each value in the IEnumerable FillRow is called with the 1st parameter as the value from the IEnumerable?

Comment: @Akash: Yes, that is what it does. I haven't written code for a table valued CLR function before, so I looked at this page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131103.aspx

Comment: Can we just simply create a list of strings and have no "FillRow" method? I don't understand why should we define two methods.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati: The method already creates an array of strings. The code interfacing with the database then calls the `FillRow` method to put the strings into the variable that is used in the table result. It seems a bit awkward when the result is a table with a single column, it makes more sense when you see it with a result that has multiple columns.

Comment: So, if the result table only has one column, can we omit the `FillRow` method? For example if I want to turn a simple string into a table of characters that only has one column.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati: You can try, but I don't think that it has any special case for single column results.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no C# expert, I'm a SQL dev, but this code has worked for me in the past. The method accepts a parameterised delimiter too.
Sorry, I cannot directly answer your question.
I can't even give you a source and credit the original author of the code - suffice to say it wasn't me.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction(Name = "StringParserCLR",
    FillRowMethodName = "FillRow",
    TableDefinition = "string nvarchar(500)")]

    public static IEnumerable StringParserCLR(SqlString str, SqlChars delimiter)
    {
        if (delimiter.Length == 0)
        {
            return new string[1] { str.Value };
        }
        return str.Value.Split(delimiter[0]);
    }

    public static void FillRow(object row, out SqlString str)
    {
        str = new SqlString((string)row);
    }
};
```